# How to detect whether triger is invoked from insert or update call?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have trigger like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_TEST1
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
..
```

If I make sql insert I want to execute select with :new flag. like that

```
BEGIN
    SELECT TEST WHERE id=:new.id        
END;
```

otherwise, if I update something, I want I want to call with :Old flag.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT TESt WHERE id=:old.id            
END;
```

How can I detect whether update was done or insert in the triger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
if updating then 
  ....
end if;

if inserting then 
  ....
end if;
```

More details on this can be found in the manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS750